# Siebel UI Automation using VB6

Tags: vb6, ui-automation, siebel

I would like to know if there is any way to be able to automation Siebel UI using VB6. Which component should i add in VB6 references to be able to get the Siebel UI objects and methods. Any help in this would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Siebel Object Interfaces Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/OIRef/OIRef_About_Object_Interfaces_and_Programming_Environment6.html)

According to the reference:

> You can access a Siebel COM object interface in any of the following
>   ways:
>
> - COM Data Control
> - COM Data Server
> - Web Client Automation Server Mobile
> - Web Client Automation Server
>
> To access a Siebel COM interface, you can use any of the following
>   languages:
>    - JavaScript
>    - Visual Basic
>    - C++

If it's installed properly, you should probably see one of these options under references--most likely under Siebel...

Mobile Web Client Automation Server requires:

> - If you use Microsoft Visual Basic version 5.0 or later, then the sobjsrv.tlb file must reside in the same directory as the Siebel
>     application configuration (CFG) file. If this file is not in the
>     correct directory, then the COM Data Server does not work.

Comment: Hi guru, Thanks for the response. I guess you are talking about connecting to Siebel DB or other components through APIs. Right now we are using QTP for automating some of the Siebel functional test cases, but I am trying to check for the solutions like how i can avoid using expensive tools like QTP, RFT etc and come up with my own solutions to be able to automate Siebel UI operations. I know that we need to get hold of Siebel_Test_Automation_... Process, but dont knw how to achieve it. this is where i need some inputs

Comment: I had already gone through these Siebel Object references earlier. It is giving the list of methods and properties associated with each Siebel Object but doesnt give any idea like how and where to start getting hold of Siebel UI Window object. (like currently how QTP / RFT access the siebel application from UI)